# Uncaught TypeError: create is not a function using useEffect React Hook with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use React hooks to fetch some data and display it, but am getting an error:

```js
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(data => {
      setUser(data.results[0]);
    }), []);
  
  return <div>
    {user ? user.name.first : 'Loading...'}
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: create is not a function
    at commitHookEffectList (react-dom.development.js:15901)
    at commitPassiveHookEffects (react-dom.development.js:15911)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at commitPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:17299)
    at wrapped (scheduler-tracing.development.js:204)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:17338)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:12035)
    at eval (index.jsx? [sm]:9)
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's because no callback function is being passed into `useEffect`. In the example above, it is actually executing the `fetch` request which doesn't return anything. Wrap the `fetch` call in an arrow/anonymous function and it will work.

```js
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => { // Pass in a callback function!
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        setUser(data.results[0]);
    });
  }, []);
  
  return <div>
    {user ? user.name.first : 'Loading...'}
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

useEffect must have a callback function. In this case you can use an arrow/anonymous function inside the brackets. `useEffect(()=>{your code})`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).